# Как из нескольких цикла foreach собрать ответ в json

Tags: php, массивы, json, foreach

Делаю возможность выгрузки данных из базы через API нужно вытащить данные Контактов (лидов), собрать из отдельной базы полей данные контакта и собрать это все в ответ формата json в таком виде

{'id_contact':'ID', 'fields':['1':{'name_input':'значение поля','vid_input':'значение поля','content':'значение поля'},'2':{'name_input':'значение поля','vid_input':'значение поля','content':'значение поля'}],'status':'ID', 'data_add':'дата', 'data_edit':'дата последнего редактирования'}

Базы:

**lids** (содержит данные id контакта, статус, дата добавления, редактирования, статус)

**input_check** (содержит названия полей так же вид поля.)

**input_content** (соответственно хранит все значения полей.  id_data - хранит ID из таблици lids и id_input_check - хранит id из таблици input_check)

Пробую собрать, но не могу понять как =(

```
if($result_input_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM input_check ORDER BY drag")) {
            $ffff = mysql_num_rows($result_input_check);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result_input_check)) {

                while($input_check_buffer = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_input_check)) {
                    $myrow_input_check[] = $input_check_buffer;
                }
            }
            else {$error = "<div class='alert alert-error'><b>Ошибка!</b> - данного лида нет в базе или у вас нет к нему доступа!</div>";}
            }
            // таблица контактов
            $result_contact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE delete_status = '0'");

                $json_output = array();
                while($row_contact = mysql_fetch_array($result_contact)){

                    //$input_info_array = array();
                    foreach($myrow_input_check as $orders_input_check) {
                            if ($orders_input_check['status'] == 1) {   
                                $result_input_content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM input_content WHERE id_data = '".$row_contact['id']."' and id_input_check = '".$orders_input_check['id']."'");
                                $row_input_content = mysql_fetch_array($result_input_content);

                                if ($row_input_content['content']) {
                                    $content = $row_input_content['content'];
                                } else {
                                    $content = '...';
                                }

                                $result_input_type = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM input_type WHERE id = '".$orders_input_check['id_input_type']."'");
                                $row_input_type = mysql_fetch_array($result_input_type);

                                $json_output[$row_contact['id']][iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8",$orders_input_check['name_input'])] = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $content);
                            }
                        }




                }

            echo json_encode($json_output);
```

Comment: Для начала стоит придерживаться синтаксически корректных конструкций... Что, например, обозначает `$json['id_contact' => $row['id']]`?

Comment: @vp_arth пытался как-то сделать... {'id_contact':'ID', ...} эту часть...